# Get data from Json Post request PHP

Tags: php, json, post

Hey guys im currently working on a salesforce project and ive setup a webhook to pass some data however the webhook is running fine but its listener is not getting the data. The data is coming in Json format here is what it looks like

```
{
 new: [
  {
   attributes: {
   IsDeleted: false,
   CleanStatus: "Pending",
   IsEmailBounced: false,
   DoNotCall: false,
   OwnerId: "0058a00000Knm0yAAB",
   FirstName: "fasdf",
   HasOptedOutOfEmail: false,
   HasOptedOutOfFax: false,
   LastName: "asdfasdf",
   Salutation: "Ms."
   }
  ],
 old: [ ],
 userId: "0058a00000Knm0yAAB"
}
```

and this is what im using to read to Json data but with no success

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

It keeps giving me NULL as the value. Any help provided would be grateful

Comment: If you're getting null, use `json_last_error()` to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your original post had `-` at the beginning of each line of the JSON, but I assumed that was a posting problem and removed it. If that was actually in the JSON, that would cause `json_decode()` to fail.

Comment: Tried the json_last_error() but there are no errors recorded

Comment: Ok well that's interesting because I unfortunately cant change the way the json data is sent. Its coming from salesforce so how can i work around that?

Comment: If it actually has those hyphens then it's *not* JSON. But then you should get something from `json_last_error()`, too.

Comment: You could try using `json_decode(preg_replace('/^\s*-/m', '', file_get_contents('php://input')), true)` to remove the hyphens before decoding.

Comment: Still no errors. I think that it is a JSON here is a test server that is showing the data that I should get back from salesforce. 
https://echo-webhook.herokuapp.com/testWebhookTrigger

I think those hyphens may have been added by stackoverflow. This is the first time im making a post so i must have done something wrong there.

Comment: If you change it to `$data = file_get_content('php://input');` you see the JSON in the var_dump?

Comment: Yes i did try that and it returns string(0) ""

Comment: Then that's the problem -- you're not actually getting any JSON in the request body. Something's wrong with how the webhook is being called.

Comment: Ok no problem. I've reached out to the guy that made the script that makes the webhooks but he hasnt responded yet. Hopefully ill be able to sort it out with him.

I appreciate the assistance

Comment: You can take a look at the script used to make the webhook here https://jamesward.com/2014/06/30/create-webhooks-on-salesforce-com/

Comment: The problem isn't the webhook, it's the server calling it.

Comment: Meaning the salesforce side or the server im hosting on. Im a bit new to these concepts.

Comment: _"It keeps giving me NULL"_ - and where exactly is it doing that ...? Did you simply call your script URL yourself in your browser? That's not how it works. This script is requested by _their_ servers, so you don't get to "see" its output anywhere. You would have to write any debug data to a file or something, and check the content of that afterwards.

Comment: Hey @CBroe the script that I wrote is also trying to log the data it receives to a file but still the file returns nothing. How would I write the debug data to a file when the server that is requesting the script doesn't belong to me?

Comment: Who owns the requesting server, has nothing to do with that. You want to write the data that _your_ server received, into a file on _your_ server, so that you can check the contents of that file afterwards.

Comment: And please log what `file_get_contents('php://input')` gets you first of all. If that was not valid JSON, then `json_decode` will of course return Null, but that gives us rather little useful information. (And btw., what your question currently shows as JSON, is _not_ valid JSON. Might be due to edits though.)

Comment: I have logged what `file_get_contents('php://input')` is getting and the file is always empty. So the data returned from the test webhook listener is as follows:

`{
new: [
{
attributes: {
type: "Contact"
},
IsDeleted: false,
CleanStatus: "Pending",
IsEmailBounced: false,
DoNotCall: false,
OwnerId: "0058a00000Knm0yAAB",
FirstName: "James",
HasOptedOutOfEmail: false,
HasOptedOutOfFax: false,
LastName: "Like",
Salutation: "Dr."
}
],
old: [ ],
userId: "0058a00000Knm0yAAB"
} `

This seems to be JSON formatting to me.